# Android libgdx bouncy screen bounds

Tags: android, libgdx, game-physics, bounce

I need to set phone's bounds as a wall where elements inside can bounce. The physic should be correct. Here an example :

[image]

I know that Interpolation allow bounce but I don't know how to create the physics

Comment: if you've already implemented X,Y coordinates for location and Vx, Vy for velocity, then you literally just need to check if the edge of the object is out of bounds, and if yes, then move it back inside the square and invert the velocity (or if you want to get fancier, then you need to check the angle with the surface and determine the new angle and thus the new velocities, also including a reduction of speed in case you want that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the collisions with the walls.  I'm assuming you're rendering Bitmaps, so the origin of the square we'll say is the top left corner.  In that case:

```
if (x + width >= SCREEN_WIDTH || x <= 0) vx *= -1;
if (y + height >= SCREEN_HEIGHT || y <= 0) vy *= -1;
```

Where vx and vy are the x and y velocities.